# cv2 findChessboardCorners does not detect corners

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, vision

I want to try out [this](https://medium.com/@omar.ps16/stereo-3d-reconstruction-with-opencv-using-an-iphone-camera-part-i-c013907d1ab5) tutorial and therefore used the code from [here](https://github.com/OmarPadierna/3DReconstruction/blob/master/Calibration/calibrate.py) in order to calibrate my camera.
I use this image:
[image]

The only thing I adapted was `chessboard_size = (14,9)` so that it matches the corners of my image.
I don't know what I do wrong. I tried multiple chessboard pattern and cameras but still cv2.findChessboardCorners always fails detecting corners.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have a defect in your pattern. bottom, center-right. -- just use "charuco". -- also... if the printer isn't accurate enough, display the pattern on a computer screen.

Comment: Both, suggestions are great. I will investigate charuco. Further, it seems to suffice to display the pattern on the screen. No need to print it physically.

Comment: btw, all the aruco "examples" in opencv seem to be C++, which I would find inconvenient. if you wanna approach this with python, go ahead. the C++ sample code looks easy enough to translate and if not, I might be willing to look at specific issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I could do it. I had to set `chessboard_size = (12,7)` then it worked. I had to count the internal number of horizontal and vertical corners.